# How to install only several components of jsxgraph?

Tags: jsxgraph

I use NodeJS and I would like to use several components of jsxgraph but not all! So I don't want to use cdnjs.

In other words I need to have my personal build of jsxgraph (because I in my app I don't need to have a property like "lastDragTime: Sat Oct 13 2018 22:17:36 GMT+...")

How can I install only several components (that I need) of jsxgraph? And what file do I need to add as a main script into html?

(I use Windows)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSXGraph is using AMD for modularization, see https://requirejs.org/docs/whyamd.html  . In theory, you can download the source of JSXgraph from https://github.com and use just the relevant modules. With require.js you can bundle everything together. Unfortunately, you will not be able to save much bytes, since for most applications all parts of JSXGraph are needed somehow. 
Moreover, with the AMD approach you can not remove individual properties like `lastDragTime`.
But I do not consider this as a major downside, since the compressed size of JSXGraph is approx. 150kByte. It will be hard to decrease this size by a significant factor by removing some of the lesser used JSXGraph properties.

I do not know, if I understand you right, but it may be an option for your project to deliver your own copy of `jsxgraphcore.js` which is totally ok.

Best wishes,
Alfred

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'm really happy to meet you here) And thank you for creating JSXGraph! I know that JSXGraph is only 150kByte, but as a developer I always try to use only those things that app needs. It is just a habit )